# Analysis Convergent Series and Integrability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm working on a quesiton in Stein's Real Analysis book; it's Chapter 2, Exercise 10.

Suppose that $f \geq 0$ is measurable, in the sense of Lebesgue. Define $E_{k} =\{x \colon 2^k < f(x) \leq 2^{k+1}\}$ and $E_{2^k} = \{x \colon 2^k < f(x)\}$.

I'm having trouble with this implication:

$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(F_k) < \infty \implies \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(E_{2^k}) < \infty$.

I have the beginning of an idea, which I will post below. If anyone can offer some intuition on how to view these sets or maybe some towards the argument I have that I might be missing.  Thanks!

My Attempt:  Notice that each $F_k = E_{2^k} \setminus E_{2^{k+1}}$ and so $E_k = F_k \cup E_{2^{k+1}}$, which is a disjoint union.  Thus,

$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(E_{2^k}) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(F_k \cup E_{2^{k+1}}) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(F_{k}) + \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(E_{2^{k+1}}) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(F_{k}) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^{k+1} m(E_{2^{k+1}}),
$
....

Answer (score 1):

If the equalities you have are correct, you have
$$
\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(E_{2^k}) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(F_k) + \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty 2^{k+1} m(E_{2^{k+1}})
$$
Notice that the rightmost sum with summand $2^{k+1}m(E_{2^{k+1}})$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(E_{2^k})$ by a simple change of variables, so you can subtract this term from both sides to get:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(E_{2^k}) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(F_k) 
$$

This, of course, assumes that everything is correct to your last equality.

**EDIT**: This is edited due to the astute point in the comments noticing that if the sum I subtracted was infinite, this operation would not be defined.

Suppose that $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k m(2^k) < \infty$. Notice that $$m(E_{2^r}) = \sum\limits_{k=r}^{\infty} m(F_k)$$ so that 
$$
\sum\limits_{r=-N}^N 2^r m(E_{2^r}) = \sum\limits_{r=-N}^N \sum\limits_{k=r}^\infty 2^rm(F_k) = \sum\limits_{k=-N}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{r=-N}^{\min(k,N)} 2^r m(F_k) = \sum\limits_{k=-N}^{\infty} 2^k m(F_k) \sum\limits_{r=-N}^{\min(k,N)} 2^{r-k} \\
\leq C \sum\limits_{k=-N}^{\infty} 2^k m(F_k) 
$$
where $C < \infty$ can be chosen independent of $N$; in fact, you could choose $C = \sum\limits_{r = -\infty}^{\infty} 2^{-|r|}$.

Comment: I had noticed that actually, but my worry was that, if $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^k  m(E_{2^k})$ was infinite, then subtracting it would do nothing, since it would be an unknown.

Comment: @m2271r You make a great point. See edit